# What does $| A |$ denote?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation, fluid-dynamics

Let us suppose we have a diagonalisable $5 \times 5$ matrix $A$. What is the meaning of $|A|$?

I am a student of fluid dynamics. I am referring to the Blazek's  [Computational Fluid Dynamics: Principles and applications](https://doi.org/10.1016/B978-0-08-044506-9.X5000-0) (2nd edition). I am referring to Roe flux discretization, where $A$ is a Roe matrix, and in the flux equation, we have $|A|$.

Surely, it would be useful to know this concept in detail.

Comment: Typically, $|\mathbf{A}|$ would be a notation for one of several [matrix norms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm). Can you provide a link to something illustrating the context and usage?

Comment: I would disagree with @JohnBarber and say that $|\mathbf{A}|$ is likely to be the determinant of $\mathbf{A}$, but would agree that context and usage would be very handy here.

Comment: @TheoBendit You're probably right. I had forgotten that the single bars $|...|$ **do** usually indicate a determinant, although that notation has always seemed unnecessarily confusing to me, since the single bars are occasionally used to indicate a norm instead of double bars.

Comment: I think it is not the determinant. Maybe the absolute value of each element in that matrix. But not sure. Therefore, I wanted to clear my doubt.

Comment: @BideshSengupta Here's one way we can know for sure: I assume that $\mathbf{A}$ represents a physical quantity. Does the matrix $\mathbf{A}$ have units? If so, is it clear from context whether $|\mathbf{A}|$ has the same units as $\mathbf{A}$, or not?

Comment: @BideshSengupta Another thought occurs: if you think that the result is a matrix, not a scalar, then it could be $\sqrt{A^*A}$, where the square root is, as per usual, the unique positive-semidefinite matrix $B$ such that $B^2 = A^*A$. This is also not uncommon. Defining $|A|$ to be the matrix of absolute values of entries of $A$ is highly unusual (and doesn't have nice linear algebra properties), but it's impossible to say for sure without seeing the book. You could take a photo of the entry in question? It's better if you could type out the quote yourself though.

Comment: F is convective flux at interface, F = 0.5(F(W_R)+F(W_L)+|A|(W_R-W_L)), where A is Roe matrix, W_R and W_L are right and left state of the interface.

Comment: A is a diagonalizable matrix, the function of fluid properties and flow properties. W is a vector. W(0)=rho, W(1)=rho*u, W(2)=rho*v, W(3)=eho*E, where V=(u,v).(n_x,n_y)

Comment: F is a vector of flux. F(0)=rho*V, F(1)=rho*u*V+n_x*p, F(2)=rho*v*V+n_y*p, F(3)=rho*H*V. Here, (n_x, n_y) is a unit normal vectors of the interface, p=pressure, rho=density, V=contravarient velocity as defined above. E is internal energy, H is enthalpy, H= E+p/rho

Comment: What are the _units_ of all the quantities you just described? What are the units of $F$, $W_R$, and $W_L$? On the right hand side, does $F(W_R)$ mean $F$ _times_ $W_R$, or is it some function of $W_R$?

Comment: Units: W(0)=kg/m^3, W(1)=Kg/m^3*m/s=W(2), W(3)=kg/m^3*(joule/kg). F(W_R) means flux (F) as the function of W_R. Unit of F(i) = unit of W(i)*(m/s)

Comment: In the concept of finite volume method, let us have two cells, two cells will be having a common wall, imagine that wall as interface. We need to calculate flux across that wall or interface. F(W_R) means flux as the function of W corresponding to the right cell. (The two cells are right cell and left cell, having a common wall which is called as interface)

Comment: From your answer, I still can't tell what the units of the quantities in your first equation ($F = 0.5(F(W_R) + F(W_L) + |A|(W_R - W_L)$) are. The reason I harp on the question of the units of these quantities is that they will allow us to deduce the units of $|A|$. This, in turn, will tell us whether $|A|$ is a determinant or a norm or what.

Comment: I am sorry. F is a vector. Unit of F(i) = unit of W(i)*(m/s), i=0..3, For example F(0) = kg/m^3*(m/s)=kg/(m^2 s), corresponding W_R=W_L=kg/m^3=W(0)

Comment: A is the jacobian flux matrix. A=partial (F)/partial (W). http://www.variousconsequences.com/2009/01/convective-flux-jacobians.html (shown for 1D), https://thewaythetruthandthelife.net/index/2_background/2-1_cosmological/2-1-10_physics/2-1-10-15-5_euler-equations.htm (for 3D)

Comment: OK, that all suggests that $\mathbf{A}$ and $|\mathbf{A}|$ have the same units. That means $|\mathbf{A}|$ can't be a determinant. I'm guessing $|\mathbf{A}|$ is either a norm or something nonstandard.

Comment: I got the answer in one document. https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00071691/document, in page7